# Recommended Translation Textbooks/Resources

Tags: reference-request, translation, machine-translation

Please delete this if it's not appropriate for this Stack.

I'm researching machine translation, and trying to read around the subject and understand better how human translators go about translating a document. I was wondering if there are any recommended textbooks for people who study this at university.

Comment: If I got it correctly... You're asking about how humans translate as in, what happens in their brains? Or the methods? In the first case, I think that would be Neurolinguistics (on topic), but I'm not sure if this is what you meant. (Let me know so I can retag your question accordingly and fix the wording.)

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the MIT book [Readings in Machine Translations](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yx3lEVJMBmMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=readings%20in%20machine%20translation&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7vioT6msHOnY4QSl2LnRCA&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=readings%20in%20machine%20translation&f=false)
by Sergei Nirenburg.  And you may also already be familiar with [Why Translation Studies Matters](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6eGPANEvSmUC&pg=PT104&dq=why%20translation%20studies%20matter&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h_moT_b7I8j74QSKq6WkDw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Gile, Hansen & Pokorn.